Cython function to return array of mpz_t objects
I am trying to write a Cython function which returns an array of mpz_t (number type of integers from the gmpy2 library). I can successfully define a fixed-size array:
cpdef void pows(mpz number):
    cdef:
        int x
        mpz_t powers[10]

    for 1 <= x <= 10:
        # do stuff and store in powers

however I want to be able to define a dynamic-size array of mpz_t (i.e. to start with it empty and add values to it) and then return powers from this function. When defining the return type, so far I have tried:
cpdef mpt_t pows(mpz number):

cpdef mpz_t[:] pows(mpz number):

cpdef mpz_t * pows(mpz number):

none of which have worked. Is this possible to do?

cpdef functions need to be callable from Python, which means that any return type must either be a Python object or just be possible to convert to a Python object.

Okay, how do I make this compatible with an array of mpz_t?

Probably declare cdef class that wraps an mpz_t (and return a list of them) or declare a cdef class that wraps an array of mpz_t.

Any ideas how to do this in a way that can be passed back to python (and is still very efficient)?
